# MSAL library always uses accounts[0]. How to get the account which was selected in account picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I am currently using Msal react library for Azure authentication.I am currently in the situation of 2 accounts signed in but my code picks up the first one in accounts array which is `accounts[0]`. [image]

How to get the account selected here?

Answer (score 1):

When signing in the user you can set the active account:

```
const { instance } = useMsal();
instance.loginPopup().then((response) => {
        // After a successful login set the active account to be the user that just logged in
        instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
    });
```

now you can retrieve the active account using:

```
instance.getActiveAccount()
```